# Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'xxx' in relationship 'xxx'... the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have th following Model:

```
    public class Annonce
    {
        [Key]
        public int annonceID { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("User")]
        public int userID { get; set; }
        public virtual User users { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Sous type")]
        public int sous_type_annonceID { get; set; }
        public virtual Sous_type_annonce sous_type_annonces { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Gouvernorat")]
        public int gouvernoratID { get; set; }
        public virtual Gouvernorat gouvernorats { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to define 3 a 1 to many relationship in the same Entity

this is my DbContext :

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Annonce>().HasRequired(p => p.gouvernorats)
            .WithMany(b => b.Annonces).HasForeignKey(b => b.annonceID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Annonce>().HasRequired(p => p.sous_type_annonces)
            .WithMany(b => b.Annonces).HasForeignKey(b => b.sous_type_annonceID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Annonce>().HasRequired(p => p.users)
            .WithMany(b => b.Annonces).HasForeignKey(b => b.sous_type_annonceID);
```

and the  Gouvernorat, User and Sous_type_annonce have this ICollection:

```
public virtual ICollection<Annonce> Annonces { get; set; }
```

I'm getting the validation errors

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Annonce_gouvernorats_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'Annonce_gouvernorats_Source' in relationship 'Annonce_gouvernorats'.
>   Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper
>   bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

What is wrong and How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Annonce>().HasRequired(p => p.gouvernorats)
   .WithMany(b => b.Annonces).HasForeignKey(b => b.gouvernoratID);
```

with "gouvernoratID" and not "annonceID"

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Annonce>().HasRequired(p => p.gouvernorats)
            .WithMany(b => b.Annonces).HasForeignKey(b => b.annonceID);
```